# What's the reason for not allowing private pilots to get paid for their services?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa, pilot-certification

As per a [recent answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/99145/2172):

> - A **Private Pilot** certificate removes a lot of the restrictions
>   of the recreational cert. You're no longer restricted in where you can
>   fly*, the number of passengers you can carry, can fly at night, and
>   are even allowed some (very limited) business use. You still can't be
>   compensated for being a pilot, though.
> - A **Commercial Pilot** certificate allows you to work as a pilot,
>   and fly for compensation or hire.

But... why does this distinction exist? If you can be trusted to fly safely on a Private Pilot license, why can't you be trusted to do the exact same thing while getting paid?

Answer (score 5):

Nobody can be trusted to fly 100% safely. It doesn't matter if you are a brand-new private pilot or a 10000 hour ATP, flying always involves some level of risk. This risk hopefully decreases as pilots gain more proficiency, and the logic is that the more you are exposing the general public to risk, the lower that risk should be.

This is also why different levels of medical certification exist- the FAA accepts that is reasonable to accept a greater level of risk to yourself and your family and friends than it is to expose the general public to.

There are also some additional risks directly involved with receiving compensation. A "[mission mindset](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2009/january/pilot/safety-pilot-mission-mindset)," where a pilot may accept unacceptable risks because they are too focused on their mission, is already a contributor to many general aviation accidents even when compensation is not involved. It goes without saying that being paid to do something adds additional pressure that may influence any pilot to decide to fly when a no-go decision would be more appropriate.

Comment: Do you know if lobbying by pilot unions had something to do with it as well?

Comment: @JonathanReez, I doubt there's any need to lobby - it really isn't very controversial to require a higher standard of a professional.  Would you hire a Private Pilot over a Commercial Pilot?

Comment: @MichaelHall yes, I definitely would, as I've previously taken several flights with a friend of mine who has a Private Pilot license. Whether or not I'm paying for the flight doesn't change how I perceive the level of risk. If it's acceptable free of charge it's also acceptable when I'm paying and vice versa.

Comment: Fair enough then, but there's a level of trust and knowledge you have with your friend that the general public doesn't have with a stranger.

Comment: Anyway, there are plenty of other businesses that require a higher standard of training and certification for professionals vs amateurs, most with far less risk to property and life at stake than piloting.  Heck, you can go to jail for offering free haircuts to the homeless without a barber's license!  Most things need to be earned... so why would you advocate for granting full commercial privileges to a fresh private pilot?

Comment: @MichaelHall sure, but it doesn't mean it should necessarily be banned? If you don't trust a fresh pilot, you don't fly with them. I just don't see why the exchange of money makes any difference whatsoever.

Comment: But the public doesn't know that.  How would you know whether or not to trust a pilot you've never met?  There is a general presumption that someone advertising commercial services (of any sort) has been vetted somehow, and is qualified and competent to do what they advertise.  What part of that do you not understand or agree with?

Comment: @MichaelHall I've read similar arguments 10 years ago about Uber :-) People were fuming about how we need all these professional drivers carrying passengers, because somehow the exchange of money makes it a lot less safe. Or people would claim that a pro driver can beat Google Maps, so non-pros should not be allowed to pick up passengers. Luckily that debate has now been settled. I'm trying to understand if this is merely a lobby-influenced Uber vs. "Pros" kind of debate or if things are actually different in aviation.

Comment: That's a reasonable comparison, but don't expect the FAA to change their minds on this one.

Comment: @JonathanReez Here in the UK uber drivers are quite reasonably held to the same standards as other taxi drivers, they aren't exempted.

Comment: @Dan yes the UK/London has some of the strongest taxi lobbyists in the world so they haven’t fully adapted the Uber model. Most other countries did though and taxi mafias are now a thing of the past.

Comment: @JonathanReez Flying via airlines is the safest form of transportation there is. General aviation is much much less safe. It's a much bigger difference than between taxis and uber drivers.

Answer (score -2):

That one is not so much a decision of the FAA, but rather the power vested in Congress, under Article 1, Section 8 of the US Constitution, giving it broad discretionary power to regulate interstate and international commerce.  As such, Congress can have a very large reach in these matters, and demand that pilots who are part of such commerce be subjected to higher standards of scrutiny, than people flying for purely recreational purposes.

Now exactly what a higher level of aviator skill for interstate commerce flying has to do with requiring a pilot be able to perform interesting but stupid parlor tricks like lazy eights and watered down chandelles is beyond me.  The majority of commercial jobs as a pilot are out of reach until you obtain an airline transport pilot’s license as well.  Ultimately the real reason that you cannot fly for compensation or higher (or may do so in a very limited capacity - see §61.113) is because the government says so.

Comment: Unfortunately this narrow interpretation of the Commerce Clause is long obsolete. The Supreme Court [ruled all the way back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wickard_v._Filburn) in 1942 that even someone who doesn't participate in commerce can still be subject to Congressional regulation. So the Feds could easily restrict non-commercial aviation as well if they so desired.

Comment: I am focusing more on commercial aviation than recreational aviation with this post.